# Deleting elements from an external JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm still learning python, and I'm writing a classic password manager app. It uses an external JSON file to store the data:

```
{
"info": [
    {
        "website_url": "1",
        "username": "1",
        "password": "1"
    },
    {
        "website_url": "2",
        "username": "2",
        "password": "2"
    },
    {
        "website_url": "3",
        "username": "3",
        "password": "3"
    },
    {
        "website_url": "4",
        "username": "4",
        "password": "4"
    }
]
}
```

I want to add an option to delete login information *from the file*, but I don't really know what to do right now. Here's my code for the feature (I'm using the JSON library):

```
url = input('Paste Login Page URL Here : ')
with open(INFO_PATH) as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      for info in data['info']:
        if info['website_url'] == url:
          del info
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Re-write the file after making those changes to the data structure. Files are **just** bytes, and they don't have an "insert mode". It is almost never the right idea to try to modify a file "directly", especially if it's in a text format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deserialize your json file to a Python object, delete the entry from it and after serialize the object to the same file, so rewriting the content. In your case you json file does not coincide with a json array but it is an json object that contains a json array labelled with "info", so you have to extract this field from it. This can be done like below:

```
import json

url = input('Paste Login Page URL Here : ')
with open(INFO_PATH, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)['info'] #data coincides with the json info array
    data = [info for info in data if info['website_url'] != url]

#overwrite the json file content with the new data
with open(INFO_PATH, 'w') as file:
    json.dump({'info': data}, file)
```